# How can I make sure that all threads ended before the main thread ends?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following piece of code to employ java multi-threading.

```
    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    while(resultSet.next()) 
       { 
          name=resultSet.getString("hName");
          MyRunnable worker = new  Myrunnable(name);
          threadExecutor.execute( worker );
          Counter++;
    }


 threadExecutor.shutdown();
 System.out.println("thread shutdown");

 // Wait until all threads are finish
 while (! threadExecutor.isTerminated()) {

 }

 System.out.println("Finished all threads");

}// end try
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("END MAIN");

    DBConnection.con.close();
```

And the run function as follows:

```
//The constructor
MyRunnable (String name)  {
        this.name=name;
    }

public void run() 
{
        myclass Obj=new myclass();
        try {
            Obj.myFunction(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Got an Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(" thread exiting.");
}
```

In a previous posts, somebody suggested the following code to wait for threads to end.

```
while (! threadExecutor.isTerminated()) {
   try {
       threadExecutor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECOND);
   }
   catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // you have to determine if someone can interrupt your wait
        // for the full termination of the executor, but most likely,
        // you'll do nothing here and swallow the exception, or rethrow
        // it in a RuntimeException
   }
}
```

Now, I'm facing problem in both cases. If I used the 1st method, my program runs but at the end it enters an infinite loop preceded by all threads exiting. The END MAIN print out never appears. If I used the 2nd method, I got the following error from the beginning of running the program, and also the END MAIN print out never appears:

> Got an Exception: No operations allowed after connection closed.
>    thread exiting.

Please, advise me in the correct way to make my Main thread exits after all my child threads exit.

Comment: The while loop could be starving the scheduler, try putting a Thread.sleep(250) or Theead.yield in it

Comment: where to put Thread.sleep(250) or Theead.yield ? Could you please clarify more as I'm new to deal with multi-threadings.

Comment: Sorry, in the while loop that you are using to wait for the other thread to finish

Comment: @Jury A: Are you sure all your tasks terminate properly?

Comment: By testing the code in a single thread, everything terminates properly.

Comment: But in the multithreaded scenario do you see the ending printouts for all tasks?

Comment: @Tudor: How can I know which thread is the one that does not end?? I.e, as you can see from the instructor that I have, each thread has a name. How can I print out in the loop the name for the thread that does not end ??

Comment: @Jury A: Just print it at the end of the `run` method for each thread.

Comment: Can't I print it inside the loop to know which thread is causing the problem & infinite loop ?

Comment: Also, inside the run, do I have to end the thread explicitly ??

Comment: @Jury A: No, the thread will terminate when `run` finishes. Why print the message in the loop when you can print it at the end of `run` where you also have the name?

Comment: The last host name prints. So, it means it ends. Why my program does stay for ever in the infinite loop ?? It does not ends. Even when added : threadExecutor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECOND); When I try small amount of records from the DB (20 to 30), it ends, when I run the actual program that reads thousands of records, the problem occur. I'm using 10 threads, do you think reducing the number of threads may help ?

Answer (score 3):

First off, why all the busy spinning? The most CPU-efficient method is to just put a very loooong `awaitTermination`:

```
threadExecutor.shutdown();
threadExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

As for the cause for the pool not terminating it's most likely because your thread tasks are not terminating properly.

Comment: But I don't want my program to run for days. I need it to end as soon as the threads finish the work. When I tried the same program with the same number of threads for less number of names (I read names from DB as shown on the code), for example, for 6 names the program start and ends perfectly. But when I read 2000 names, the last threads does not end. It stays forever. Also, System.out.println("thread shutdown"); never print out.

Comment: @JuryA The suggestion above will block until all the threads have completed before returning. It is an improvement because you wait once with a large timeout, rather than waiting many times with a small timeout.